# Super slow mksquashfs involving Wine?

Tags: backup, disk-image, snapshot

My Ubuntu install is on SSD drive ext4 format with LVM.
I'm making a 'backup' by:
Creating a snapshot, then using mksquashfs to copy the snapshot to an external drive.

The problem is after a short while, the process grinds to a slow and unsatisfying snail's pace. All 8 processors start out at 100% and the squash image progress proceeds nicely. Then, all of a sudden, hardly anything happens and System Monitor showing all Cpu's drop to idle usage. A disk monitor (iotop) shows basically nothing happening with disk. So, I used the -info option in mksquashfs to see what was going on - and what is happening is it's slowing down on /home/user/.wine files. It was also doing this slowness on files that seemingly don't even exist: I had installed, then uninstalled PlayOnLinux. But, there was backing up of /home/user/.local/share/Trash/files/.Playonlinux -??? which doesn't exist if I try to find it.

I also notice that when I initially start Windows-Wine apps, especially the first time after booting, it takes forever. Don't know if it's related. I'm talking like more than 60 seconds to start up a pretty simple Windows program. (Machine has i7 processor and 48gb ram and only SSD drives)
After some hours and it gets through with the wine files, things speed up a lot as cpu goes back to 100% and files processed like crazy. Until it gets to my VMware VirtualBox files - slow again. Then, fast again through 'native ubuntu' stuff, until it gets to /opt/wine-stable/.. files - slow again.

Where have I gone wrong? And how do I really get rid of all the PlayonLinux phantom files/trash? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

The slowness not caused by Wine, but by Sophos Antivirus free (SAV) -
If I kill Sophos, the problem goes away.